# How to determine branch name from batch file

Tags: batch-file, tfs, branch, tf-cli

I did a get latest from TFS.
My local path is:

`C:\tfs\Project\Branch1\Config\Deployment\CopyInstallers.bat`

TFS Path is:

`$\Project\Branch1\Config\Deployment\CopyInstallers.bat`

`CopyInstallers.bat` gets latest of installer folder from the branch at different location on the server and zips them and puts it on the shared location on server.

I have another branch named `Branch2` and its TFS path is

```
$\Project\Branch2\Config\Deployment\CopyInstallers.bat
```

What I am trying is try to get the branch name using `TF.exe` or `TFPT.exe`, so that I should not har code the branch name in the `CopyInstaller.bat` file to get latest of installer folder.

Or is there any other way by which I can get to know the branch name / path with in the batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the TF.EXE info command.

1. From the DOS Shell go to the directory in your workspace where the branch is located (C:\tfs\Project\Branch1\Config\Deployment)
2. Use the command : `TF.EXE info .`
3. Parse the result on the "Server Path:" line.

**EDIT :**
With Visual Studio 2010 replace the `info` command by the `properties` one

**EDIT 2**

Ok: I made you a console app, get the [zip file here](http://loicbaumann.fr/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/GetBranchFromPath.zip), there's the sources code and build exe.

Tell me if it's what you expected

Comment: There is not such command as "info" on the TF.exe Even tried using TFPT.exe (Powertool) and it also doesnot have it.

Comment: Argh, you're right, it's a new command of Visual Studio 11. It doesn't exist for Visual Studio 2010. I look for another way.

Comment: Properties command does return the Server Path String, but the main question is how to identify the branch name. THanks but I am looking for a way by which i can get directly the branch name / path to which the file belongs to.

Comment: If you know the location on your workspace of the Branch then use this command to retrive the server path the last directory will be the branch name, right ?
For me the Branch name is the name of the folder, I can't see something else, can you be more explicit ?

Comment: In the above example path $\Project\Branch1\Config\Deployment\CopyInstallers.bat "Branch1" is my Development branch. This is the name OR $\Project\Branch1 path which i want to be able to retrieve by using a command.

Comment: Hang on I'll make you a small app for that. You use a TFS 2010 or TFSPreview.com ?

Comment: I use TFS 2010 and TFS PowerTools

Comment: Have you tested the Console App I made?

Comment: Sorry Nock, was away for very long time and not bound to the respective project. It worked for me.