# History with diffs embedded

Tags: version-control, powershell, tfs, tf-cli

To see the history of each checkin a user has done in a directory tree i can type:

```
tf history . /recursive /user:name /noprompt /format:detailed
```

It displays all checkins "name" has performed with checkin comments and paths to the changed files. I want to display, in addition to that, the diff of each affected file. Like /format:extraverbose. Is there a way to have tf do that? If not, how can you create a powershell script that does that for me?

You can disregard things like branches and merges - there are none in the directory tree.

Comment: by "the diff of each affected file" you mean added/removed/changed lines ?

Comment: Yep, exactly. The builtin diff-format that ``tf diff . /noprompt`` uses would work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a command line for that right now, maybe you can create a Powershell script using the [TFS Powertools CmdLet](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f).

Otherwise you can still make a command line exe using the TFS API, it's easier than one might think. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10332745/802124) to get the source files of a command line tool that I made for someone.